# Находит элемент JSON но в логе ошибка! Что не так?

Tags: php

JSON файл

```
[
  {
    "name": "value2",
    "id": 2,
    "test": [
      {
        "leave": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Код php:

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents('test.json');
$g = json_decode($f, true);

foreach ($g as $val) {
    foreach ($val['test'] as $key => $value) { // <--- строка 6
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

Результат работы кода:

```
Array ( [leave] => 5 )
```

Верно.
Но почему в логах ошибки?

```
[20-Feb-2019 20:24:48 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: test in  .... /test.php on line 6
[20-Feb-2019 20:24:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .... test.php on line 6
```

Comment: вы уверены, что данные строки лога не относятся к каким-либо предыдущим запускам скрипта?  не воспроизводится.

Comment: а если попробовать заменить `$val['test']` на `(array) $val['test']`?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie нет никакого смысла конвертировать несуществующую переменную в массив.

Comment: @teran нет никаких предыдущих запусков, это весь тестовый скрипт.

Comment: я и не говорю что это не весь скрипт. я говорю, что может вы написали шляпу какую-то, запустили, получили ошибку. Исправили, запускаете снова и смотрите в логи на старые ошибки.

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте так

```
 $g = json_decode($f, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```